# RF receiver always having 1 on output

Tags: arduino, rf, receiver

So my problem is I want to build a wireless system with arduino and an RF module.
It is like this one:

[image]

But when I tested the module, with this site:

https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-test-RF-transmitter-and-receiver-before-pro/

my LED is always on, even without transmitter...

What can possibly cause this?

Datasheet for my modules: 
https://www.hestore.hu/prod_getfile.php?id=8203

Thanks for the replies[image]
[image]

Comment: We cannot help you if we know nothing about the  part. Showing us photos of the boards does not tell us anything useful about them. We either need datasheets or part numbers to find the datasheet (but since you're asking you should just use the part number and supply us with the datasheet). You also have not provided us a schematic. We can't tell how you intended to wire things up from a photo with wires everywhere.

Comment: In actuality, the output of the receiver is almost certainly *toggling* (unless it is defective or receiving a very strong signal), but doing so too quickly to see.  This is fundamental to the design of regenerative receivers.  You will not be able to use such a radio to control something without adding an additional function block to recognize a particular coded pattern, as things like remote controlled outlets, relay modules, or appliances do.  You will likely find code to do this with an Arduino, but questions seeking to find library code are off topic.

Comment: (You will also need an encoder for the transmitter, such as another Arduino, or to replace the current transmitter with a keyfob on the same frequency that already has an encoder, figure out what code it is sending, and configure the receiver library to look for that)

Comment: @DKNguyen the datasheet is not very amazing https://www.hestore.hu/prod_getfile.php?id=8203

Comment: @huistbor Yeah. Crappy datasheets seem typical with no-name products from China. In the future, I recommend you not buy something without a proper datasheet.

Comment: @DKNguyen I also added the wiring, but honestly it's just powering up the receiver.

Comment: @huistbor Not enough information for me to help you. Chris Stratton seems like has has more experience with these types of modules so go with what he says. I hope you have an oscilloscope.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Uhm I can see it flicker sometimes, so you are right maybe, But when I try to send data from my arduino 1 to arduino 2 it just doesn't arrives, so I decided to test it and does this.. BTW I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAJqTvYnESI
Tomorrow I will measure it. I hope its just a bad soldering, I will tell you

Comment: And @DKNguyen I have access to an oscilloscope, tomorrow I will have more infomation for you. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the datasheet doesn't say anything about it, the presence of a trimmer capacitor and lack of a crystal suggests that this receiver is a [super-regenerative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_circuit#Superregenerative_receiver) type. This uses positive feedback to increase the gain of a single transistor until it oscillates, then quenches the oscillation at a high audio frequency to produce extremely high (theoretically infinite) gain with very few parts. Because the gain is so high, if there is no signal it will simply output noise.

This board also has an [LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2904-n.pdf) op amp, which converts the audio output of the super-regenerative detector into a 'digital' on/off signal. If the 'signal' is just noise then the digital output will simply toggle on and off randomly in time with the noise. An LED connected directly to the output will appear to be lit up continuously, when in reality it is flashing randomly at audio frequencies.

When a strong enough RF signal is present the transmitted signal should appear on the receiver output. However unless the signal is very strong some noise may still be present. The device using the signal must reject this noise, by eg. only accepting pulses which have the correct shape and/or verifying that serial data matches its [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). This can be done with suitable code in an MCU, or using a dedicated chip such as the [Holtek HT12D](https://www.holtek.com/productdetail/-/vg/2_12d)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was actually very helpful. Now the problem is that I can't get it to work, The 2 arduinos are wired up,the code is fine but no message appears. 
Same situation like this: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=521245.0
Should I ask it in another question?

Comment: Okay I gave up . I soldered antennas, to the modules, still getting nothing on terminal.
I am buying nrf2401 modules instead..
thanks for the help